# liquid level switch and solenoid valve circuit

Tags: switches, ground, solenoid, level

I am trying to make sure that I have this circuit hooked up right before I actually put it to use. I’m planning to use the [liquid level switch (McMaster PN:50195K93)](http://www.mcmaster.com/#50195k93/=y5hg9s) to open the [solenoid valve (McMaster PN:4639K151)](http://www.mcmaster.com/#4639k151/=y5hgwt) and add water from the Dosing tank to the Feed tank when the liquid level is too low (see diagram below).

The liquid level switch and solenoid valve both operate on 120 VAC, but I just wanted to see if anyone can let me know if the circuit looks right. I feel like there should be a resistor between the outlet and the liquid level switch so that there is something for the voltage to drop across when the circuit is open, but I’m not sure.

Lastly, there are only two wires coming from the liquid level switch and solenoid valve (2 wires each), but is there a way to add a ground to the circuit or is that something that I shouldn't be worried about? The solenoid valve is partly made of metal (316SS) and the liquid level switch is plastic (polypropylene), but I don’t see any spot on the solenoid valve to attach a ground. Any help would be much appreciated.

[image: Solenoid valve and liquid level switch circuit diagram]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Switch you linked has a maximum current rating of 0.28 amps, and the valve has a maximum current rating of 0.41. as such you should look at a different solution. Either different parts or perhaps use a 5 volt signal to the switch that will then turn on a relay to enable to valve. And be sure to add some fuses for safety when working around water.

[image]

Comment: You could also use a 120 volt relay such as you can find here:http://www.mcmaster.com/#general-purpose-relays/=y5iswn

Comment: Don't know how I didn't notice that the different max current ratings would be problematic. We had an extra DC/AC relay laying around the lab and this worked perfectly without having to buy new parts. Thanks @kozlojak !